# Strong, weak references + Mirror: causing leak

Tags: swift

The `Parent` class below has strong & weak references to a single child object. The child object is never freed. Remove the weak reference and the child is freed.

Calling the `Mirror` method is required to make this leak, but I cannot understand why using a Mirror would cause this behavior. The results of the Mirror are not retained.

With both weak & strong refs, only the parent deinit is executed!

```
Parent deinit
```

I expect to see both parent & child objects freed, so that the log says:

```
Parent deinit
DeinitLogger deinit
```

Remove the weak reference and the log shows both objects deinit, as expected.

Can you help me understand why this is leaking? (This is not a playground, but in an app).

```
class DeinitLogger {
    deinit {
        print("DeinitLogger \(#function)")
    }
}

class Parent: NSObject {

    weak var weakLogger: DeinitLogger?
    var strongLogger: DeinitLogger

    override init() {

        let logger = DeinitLogger()

        // Create a weak ref
        weakLogger = logger  // comment out this line, no leak!

        // Create a strong ref to same object.
        strongLogger = logger

        super.init()

        // Invoking mirror and adding the properties to a dict leaks when one of the
        // properties is weak.
        let dict = dictionaryOfProps()
        print(dict)
    }

    deinit {
        print("Parent \(#function)")
    }

    /// Generates a dictionary of property names -> properties
    /// e.g. "strongLogger" -> type of strongLogger.
    private func dictionaryOfProps() -> [String: Any] {
        var result = [String: Any]()
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for case let(label?, value) in mirror.children {
            result[label] = value
        }
        return result
    }
}

// Chuck these two lines in a viewDidLoad(), or anywhere. 
var o: Parent? = Parent()
o = nil // everything should be freed here.
```

Comment: I found this issue in an App, and boiled it down into a playground. But of course, translating this code back to App and it does work properly. Argh! Back to boiling down. Thank you.

Comment: Alright... I went back to an app and changed my boiling-down recipe. Now there's a `Mirror` involved. And the weak ref + mirror causes a leak even in an app!

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, but I admit that I have no idea what is happening here. – Instead of `let dict = dictionaryOfProps(); print(dict)` it suffices to execute `for _ in Mirror(reflecting: self).children { }` in the Parent.init method.

Comment: Yes, one does have to include some iteration of the `children`. Thanks for checking my eyes. It's not obvious, is it. I think I shall open a bug against Swift.

Comment: That is https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8878, it is already fixed in the development branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a known bug in Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10):

- [SR-8878 Using Mirror to access a weak reference results in object being retained indefinitely](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8878)

caused by a missing release when reading a weak reference in [ReflectionMirror.m](https://github.com/mikeash/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/ReflectionMirror.mm). The bug has been fixed on the master branch. Your program behaves correctly with the current “Trunk Development (master)” snapshot from https://swift.org/download/#releases.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for following through with that research, Martin.